# C# insert values to string

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

Ok so basically I have a string that looks like this

"this is random text [this is random too] [another random text] hey ho [random bar]"

I want the output to be

"this is random text [[this is random too]] [[another random text]] hey ho [[random bar]]"

So basically find every [ and append an [ to it and same for the ]

What would be the best way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: @IanNorton What I actually tried was using .IndexOf and then .Insert. But that didn't work too good. I just had little sleep and this is the result of it. I even tagged replace in the question and didn't realize that i could use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So basically find every [ and append an [ to it and same for the ]

Sounds like:

```
text = text.Replace("[", "[[")
           .Replace("]", "]]");
```

to me... no need for a regular expression at all.

That is assuming you don't need to worry about brackets which are *already* doubled, of course.

Comment: I feel so stupid, this works fine. Thanks. Will accept it in 8 minutes.

Comment: @user1224096: Glad it worked - the problem being simpler than you thought is always nicer than the opposite ;)

Answer (score 1):

This will be more efficient because the array will never have to be resized. Although the difference is so small you're probably better off using Jon Skeet's method.

```
public string InsertBrackets(string text)
{
    int bracketCount = 0;
    foreach (char letter in text)
        if (letter == '[' || letter == ']')
            bracketCount++;

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(text.Length + bracketCount);

    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < text.Length && j < result.Length; i++, j++)
    {
        result[j] = text[i];

        if (text[i] == '[')
            result[++j] = '[';
        else if (text[i] == ']')
            result[++j] = ']';
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or given you've tagged this with regex:

```
var foo = "this is random text [this is random too] " +
    "[another random text] hey ho [random bar]";
var regex = new Regex(@"\[(.*?)\]");
string bar = regex.Replace(foo, @"[[$1]]");
```